# cant see breakpoints when I want to debug using device

Tags: android, debugging

When I'm using the device and click on my **debug** the application is lunched in my device but I cant see the break points  .

In the debug window the application whom run is shown for a second and then disappear and I cant debug my application on the device .

Did I miss something ? can someone please explain me what I did wrong and correct me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my problem was not adding the

```
<application android:debuggable="true".../>
```

in the right place ...

Comment: Please mark your own answer as "best answer" so that it doesn't show up as unanswered. Plus, it'll get you closer to a badge :)